# Удаление элемента из ArrayaList

Tags: java

Есть ArrayList, который состоит из String'ов. Как можно удалить те элементы, строчки в которых начинаются с пяти пробелов?

Answer (score 9):

Вариант 1:

```
Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String s = itr.next();
    if (s.startsWith("     ")) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
list = list.stream()
                .filter(s -> !s.startsWith("     "))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Вариант 3:

```
lst.removeIf(s -> s.startsWith("     "));
```